# Airflow - FTPToS3Operator over SSL/TLS

Tags: python, ftp, airflow

I would like to use the FTPToS3Operator Airflow operator to copy a file from an FTPS server to S3 bucket.

As I can see in the transfer operator's code, it uses only FTPHook to connect. Since I cannot used unsecured FTP, is there a way to use that operator with FTPS ?